# ASP.NET MVC - Html.Action returns List<string>, how to show the list correctly in view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The view has already other ActionResult and a model, but in one part of the view I need some results and I use Html.Action which returns List.

It can be compiled and the outputs are like:

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String];

How can I show correctly the value of the strings?

Comment: not clear your question, and can you please provide the  `Model` `View` `Controller` ,

Answer (score 1):

Convert explicitly to

```
List<SelectListItem>
```